# nginx limit_rate from certain file size

Tags: nginx

I have limited the download speed on my nginx site with this option:

```
limit_rate 350k;
```

Is it possible to do this only if the file size is larger then 10Mb?
Thank you.

Comment: Propably not but maybe you can put your big files under a special path/domain?

Comment: So when I put these files in folder like `big_files` then I can do it?

Comment: Yes. `limit_rate` can be put in `http`, `server`, `location` and `if` in `location`. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_rate

Comment: You could also use `limit_rate_after 10m` maybe. Then it will only start limiting after 10MB. The first 10MB will be full speed for every download though.